# Kubernetes - Container is not accessible using node port

Tags: kubernetes

Team,

Currently we have setup a kubernetes cluster with a single master and single worker node.

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-172-31-18-129.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   15h   v1.15.0
k8s-master                                     Ready    master   15h   v1.15.0

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        15h
nodeport     NodePort    10.104.192.11   <none>        80:30385/TCP   4s

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-554b9c67f9-wcsds   1/1     Running   1          15h   10.44.0.1   ip-172-31-18-129.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
[root@k8s-master ~]# curl -v 172.31.18.129:30385
* Rebuilt URL to: 172.31.18.129:30385/
*   Trying 172.31.18.129...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

Here am using my worker node ip to access my container from master. Whereas I can able to access from worker node by cluster ip, please find the output below :

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-129 ~]# curl 10.104.192.11
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What I expected to happen?

Nginx container suppose to be accessible from master using worker node ip address, but am unable to do that for some reason.

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:40:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:37:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Cloud provider or hardware configuration: AWS EC2 instances

OS (e.g: cat /etc/os-release): RHEL 8
Kernel (e.g. uname -a):
[root@k8s-master ~]# uname -a
Linux k8s-master 4.18.0-80.4.2.el8_0.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 13:20:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/L
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Are you able to access the service from outside of the cluster using **<worker node ip>:<node port>**? If you are able to access from out side of the cluster, you should be able to access from master node too. Also let me know if you can access the service using **<master node ip>:<node port>**?

Comment: I am able to access from the worker node directly like <worker-ip>:<nodeport >. But I unable to access from outside of cluster using Public IP of my worker node. Like "http://<worker-public-ip>:<node-port>"

Comment: Found the solution myself. 
I had to add the following rules on iptables of node

`iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Now I'm able access `(http://<worker-public-ip>:<node-port>)` from outside of cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Check the link below. Since you have hosted your worker node in the cloud environment, you need to achieve this through Ingress resource

https://serverfault.com/questions/946546/how-to-externally-access-a-kubernetes-service-of-type-as-nodeport-using-ec2-p

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your cloud provider firewall might be blocking the external access. Make sure you have allowed the high port (30385).

Note that this is not recommended in production, only for development and testing. Otherwise you will need to setup ingress as explained at  mhsundar's answer.